# Как передать id в функцию JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть блок с контентом и кнопка с одинаковыми id

```
<div id="1">
Какой-то контент
<button id="1" onclick="delDiv(this.id)">Удалить</button>
</div>
```

Есть функция, которая вызывается по кнопке

```
function delDiv(id) {    
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}
```

Но функция не работает. Что тут нужно исправить? Только без parentElement

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что функция не работает?

Comment: чем parentElement не угодил?

Comment: помимо этого div с id="1" есть другие div с id="1" в другой части кода. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки удалялись все div  с id="1"

Comment: замени `id` на `class`

Comment: "помимо этого div с id="1" есть другие div с id="1" в другой части кода. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки удалялись все div с id="1"" --- вот это вот всё и надо изначально указывать в вопросе.............добавил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, в таком виде всё работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно, что не работает. HTML не валидный. Когда исправите - будет работать

---

На всякий случай можно переделать под это:

```js
function delDiv(elem) {    
    elem.parentNode.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="div-1">
Какой-то контент
<button id="btn-1" onclick="delDiv(this)">Удалить</button>
</div>


<div id="div-2">
Какой-то контент
<button id="btn-2" onclick="delDiv(this)">Удалить</button>
</div>
```

т.к. на странице есть одинаковые идентификаторы...что не верно изначально

---

> помимо этого div с id="1" есть другие div с id="1" в другой части кода. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки удалялись все div с id="1"

Элементам общим признаком надо присвоить класс и работать с ним. А кнопкам можно добавить data-атрибуты, для определения общего класса

```js
function delDiv(elem) {    
    let divClass = elem.dataset.info;    
    
    [...document.querySelectorAll(`.${divClass}`)].forEach((elem) => {
       elem.style.display = "none";     
    });        
}
```

```html
<div class="common-div">
Какой-то контент
<button id="btn-1" data-info="common-div" onclick="delDiv(this)">Удалить1</button>
</div>


<div class="common-div">
Какой-то контент
<button id="btn-2" data-info="common-div" onclick="delDiv(this)">Удалить1</button>
</div>


<div class="common-div2">
Какой-то контент
<button id="btn-1" data-info="common-div2" onclick="delDiv(this)">Удалить2</button>
</div>


<div class="common-div2">
Какой-то контент
<button id="btn-2" data-info="common-div2" onclick="delDiv(this)">Удалить2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Что значит невалидный и что конкретно исправить?

Comment: ну вот только что ты поправил код в вопросе на валидный html......и теперь всё работает

Comment: Так говорю же, что функция не запускается при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: Всё запускается. Хотя HTML-разметка всё так же является не валидной из-за наличия двух одинаковых значений идентификатора у элементов

Comment: @АлександрЗинченко чем докажешь, что не работает?